# SSL versions of sites not working on 2 sites same machine and ip virtual hosts

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I have CentOS 8 I installed LAMP, Varnish, etc.

I setup hosts

/etc/hosts

```
ip site1.com www.site1.com ip site2.com www.site2.com
```

I setup Apache like this:

/etc/httpd.conf to include sites-enabled/
I have sites-enabled and sites-available with two configurations, site1.com.conf and site2.com.conf

Here what I included in etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Still it is not working. Any idea how to fix this?

I have sites-enabled and sites-available with this *.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName ip
Redirect / 301 external_site
</VirtualHost>

and 

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/site2.com/html/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/site2.com/html/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I manage to get this to work now but the https versions are not working, how to fix the https versions ?

I generate 2 ceritficates using mod_ssl

I put 1 of them in /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf ...

Fixed:
Problem was misconfiguration of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

Comment: The first `ServerName` should be `ServerName site1.com`. You should not mix IP-based and [Name-based](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) virtual hosts. `site1.com` is displaying correctly just because its config file is alphabetically before `site2.com`. For the SSL virtual hosts, you should just add the `SSLEngine on` and the [SSLCertificate*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) directives.

Comment: yes i fixed how show be instead of servername ip since i dont have a domain pointing to the server ?

Comment: Yes, but you did override `DNS` putting the two lines in `/etc/hosts`. For local usage that is enough.